# Barplot grouped by class and time-interval

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, grouped-bar-chart

I have data of request response times in a pandas dataframe

```
    execution_time  request_type    response_time_ms    URL     Error
2   2023-10-12 08:52:16     Google  91.0    https://www.google.com  NaN
3   2023-10-12 08:52:16     CNN     115.0   https://edition.cnn.com     NaN
6   2023-10-12 08:52:27     Google  90.0    https://www.google.com  NaN
7   2023-10-12 08:52:27     CNN     105.0   https://edition.cnn.com     NaN
10  2023-10-12 08:52:37     Google  5111.0  https://www.google.com  NaN
```

It contains the time of the request, request_type is simply the website name and the response time.

What I want to achieve is a barplot that groups the median response time by website (request_type) and by a time frame, say group every 4 hrs together. This should show that response time varies by daytime.

I managed to create the plot but the coloring is "off". The issue I have is that I want the different websites to be colored differently.

What I have till now:

```
df_by_time = df.groupby(["request_type", pd.Grouper(key="execution_time", freq="4h")]).agg({"response_time_ms": ["median"]})
df_by_time.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8, 6), title='Response Times', xlabel='Type', ylabel='Response time [ms]', rot=90)
```

This leads to below image:

[image: Response Times by hour]

I would like to:

- group the times together so each time only appears once with a stack in different color per website
- or at least in this plot have the different websites in different colors
- get rid of the "none, none" in the legend

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to aggregate with `'median'`, not `['median']` to avoid the MultiIndex, then you can use [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

df_by_time = (df.groupby(["request_type", pd.Grouper(key="execution_time",
                                                     freq="4h")])
                .agg({"response_time_ms": "median"})
                .reset_index()
             )

sns.barplot(data=df_by_time, x='execution_time', y='response_time_ms',
            hue='request_type')
```

Alternatively, use [`groupby.median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.median.html) to produce a Series and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to use pandas' [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df_by_time = (df.groupby(["request_type", pd.Grouper(key="execution_time", freq="4h")])
                ['response_time_ms'].median()
                .unstack('request_type')
             )

df_by_time.plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Aggregation every 20s to show you the behavior with multiple time groups:

[image]